# Однокоренные слова

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Подумалось: а ведь слова "похищать" и "восхищаться", скорее всего, однокоренные, да? Почему же такой разный смысл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, это однокоренные слова. Корень хищ- (хит-). В ***словаре В.И.Даля*** родство этих слов показано прекрасно:

ВОСХИЩАТЬ, восхитить кого, похищать, ***выхватывать, уносить***, уводить силою; увлекать в высоту; || ***возносить кого духом***, приводить в восторженное состояние, в восторг, восхищение; радовать, утешать в высшей степени. ***Восхищать у кого силу***. стар. ***одолевать***, ***побеждать кого***. —ся, возвр. и страдат. смотря по смыслу речи, во всеех знач. Восхищенный, похищенный; || о человеке, восторженный, ***отрешившийся и вознесшийся духом***; кидающийся в крайности, восторженный и самоуверенный, эксцентрический человек. Восхищение ср. действие и состояние по знач. глаг. на ть и на ся. Более употребл. в знач. восторга, неистовой радости. Восхитительный, приводящий в восхищение, в восторг. Восхитительность ж. свойство всего того, что восхищает. Восхищенность ж. свойство восхищенного, эксцентричность. Восхититель м. ‑ница ж. похититель, хищник; тать, вор; || приводящий в восхищение, в восторг.

Яндекс.Словари › Толковый словарь Даля, 1863-1866

Comment: Восх'ищенной и восхищ'енной.  
Сны видящей средь бела дня,  
Все спящей видели меня,  
Никто меня не видел сонной. 
               М.И.Цветаева